# Why Apple keeps warning even after I handled the new privacy manifest rule?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-privacy-settings, privacy-manifest

Apple's message:

```
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “{app name}” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “{app name}” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “{app name}” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “{app name}” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
```

So, I did the following to tackle the issue:

- Upgrade 3rd party SDKs that are listed in the required list of Apple so that they have their manifest.
- Out of the four API categories, only `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults` is also needed on the app side (as my app uses UserDefaults), so I added it to the app's `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy`.

However, when I submitted the new app, Apple still responded with the same warning. My understanding is privacy manifests of the App and SDKs are merged into one (or equivalent). Is that correct? What am I missing then?

### Swift Packages and versions

The log from the `xcodebuild`

```bash
[08:11:49]: ▸ Resolved source packages:
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleAppMeasurement: https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement.git @ 10.22.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleDataTransport: https://github.com/google/GoogleDataTransport.git @ 9.4.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   GTMSessionFetcher: https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher.git @ 3.3.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   UIPiPView: git@github.com:torufuruya/UIPiPView.git @ b3183e7
[08:11:49]: ▸   CwlCatchException: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlCatchException.git @ 2.1.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleSignIn: https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS @ 7.1.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   CwlPreconditionTesting: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting.git @ 2.1.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   AudioKit: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit.git @ 5.5.7
[08:11:49]: ▸   nanopb: https://github.com/firebase/nanopb.git @ 2.30910.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   AppCheck: https://github.com/google/app-check.git @ 10.18.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   Pulse: https://github.com/kean/Pulse @ 1.1.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   Quick: https://github.com/Quick/Quick.git @ 6.1.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   SwiftlySearch: https://github.com/thislooksfun/SwiftlySearch.git @ 1.2.5
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleUserMessagingPlatform: https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-user-messaging-platform.git @ 2.3.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   swift-video-generator: https://github.com/dev-labs-bg/swift-video-generator.git @ 1.4.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   AdvancedScrollView: https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/advanced-scrollview.git @ 0.0.6
[08:11:49]: ▸   GTMAppAuth: https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth.git @ 4.1.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git @ 10.22.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   SwiftyStoreKit: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit.git @ 0.16.4
[08:11:49]: ▸   Mocker: https://github.com/WeTransfer/Mocker.git @ 3.0.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   leveldb: https://github.com/firebase/leveldb.git @ 1.22.3
[08:11:49]: ▸   Promises: https://github.com/google/promises.git @ 2.4.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   abseil: https://github.com/google/abseil-cpp-binary.git @ 1.2022062300.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   URLImage: https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image @ 3.1.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   AppAuth: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS.git @ 1.7.3
[08:11:49]: ▸   SwiftProtobuf: https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf.git @ 1.25.2
[08:11:49]: ▸   swift-log: https://github.com/apple/swift-log.git @ 1.4.4
[08:11:49]: ▸   gRPC: https://github.com/google/grpc-binary.git @ 1.49.2
[08:11:49]: ▸   Mantis: https://github.com/guoyingtao/Mantis.git @ 2.7.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   Get: https://github.com/kean/Get.git @ 1.0.4
[08:11:49]: ▸   Fakery: https://github.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery @ 5.1.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   Nimble: https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git @ 11.2.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleMobileAds: https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads.git @ 11.2.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   GoogleUtilities: https://github.com/google/GoogleUtilities.git @ 7.13.1
[08:11:49]: ▸   ImagePickerView: https://github.com/ralfebert/ImagePickerView @ 0.5.0
[08:11:49]: ▸   InteropForGoogle: https://github.com/google/interop-ios-for-google-sdks.git @ 100.0.0
```

### SDKs declaring the reported API categories

The result I grep the API categories directly in the swift package checkout folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/SourcePackages/checkouts/`

#### `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp`

```bash
➜  checkouts grep NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp . -lr
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/grpcpp-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/grpc-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/openssl-grpc-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./gtm-session-fetcher/Sources/LogView/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Privacy/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
```

#### `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace`

No SDKs. It must have used in the Firebase Crashlytics but it seems to be removed in the latest version.

```
# 10.22.0
- [fixed] Force validation or rotation of FIDs for FirebaseSessions.
- [changed] Removed calls to statfs in the Crashlytics SDK to comply with Apple Privacy Manifests. This change removes support for collecting Disk Space Free in Crashlytics reports.
```

I confirmed no other APIs that require this policy listed in the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api#4278397) (e.g. `statfs`) were used in any SDKs.

#### `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime`

```bash
➜  checkouts grep NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime . -lr
./firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/grpcpp-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/grpc-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./grpc-binary/openssl-grpc-Wrapper/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
```

#### `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults`

```bash
➜  checkouts grep NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults . -lr
./GoogleSignIn-iOS/GoogleSignIn/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseCore/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseRemoteConfig/Swift/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./gtm-session-fetcher/Sources/Core/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
./GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Privacy/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
```

Comment: I noticed that I didn't add my `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` to the app target. I re-submitted and now the `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults` category is gone from Apple's message but the other three categories are remaining...

Comment: This seems to be a common occurrence when adding third-party dependencies as static frameworks, even if they already have a valid privacy manifest. It's possible it could be an issue in how App Store Connect validates these assets, but one workaround in the meantime is adding those missing declarations to your app's privacy manifest.